# Perimeter of the Mandelbrot Set?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, fractals

What would the perimeter of the mandelbrot set be? Would it be infinite? Using logical reasoning, I feel that it should be some finite number. I came to this conclusion because it could be roughly approximated with low detail then more detail could be added to get a more accurate number. However, the added detail becomes less and less significant as it is added. Therefore, it must approach some finite number.

Is this way of thinking correct? I don't believe I have the mathematical skills to calculate this number(I'm not even in university yet). would there be a way to calculate the mandelbrot set's perimeter? If so, how would you go about it? Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Hausdorff dimension may be of interest to you.

Comment: The [*Hausdorff dimension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension) of the boundary of the Mandelbrot set is $2$ and hence infinite perimeter.

Comment: A quick less technical explaination is that part of why the mandelbrot set is interesting is that when we look at smaller patches the level of complexity in the boundary doesn't decrease and so approximating by smaller line segments actually makes the boundary longer. The classical name for this is the coastline paradox and one way of measuring this is the concept of Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: @Fishbane It is not necessary to show that the boundary has Hausdorff dimension 2 in order to conclude that the perimeter is finite.  It is, in fact, sufficient to show that the boundary has Hausdorff dimension greater than 1.  From this, it will follow that the 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure (which is equivalent to the 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure, which is the "usual" measure of length) will be infinite.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am aware of that. The original version of the comment refered to the Hausdorff dimension of the mandelbrot set, not the boundary. My comment was only noting that that was in error not that $2$ was required, any value greater than $1$ will suffice (and Hausdorff dimension $1$ does not imply finite perimeter). I have now deleted my comment as it is not relevant anymore and may cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In this picture some equipotentials around the Mandelbrot set are plotted, labelled by approximate length.  As you can see, at first the lengths decrease as you get closer, but it reaches a minimum at about $14.9$ before increasing rapidly because the curves have to wriggle a lot (the shape of the Mandelbrot set is complicated).

[image: equipotentials around the Mandelbrot set labelled by length]

As per the comments on the question, the boundary of the Mandelbrot set has a Hausdorff dimension strictly greater than $1$, that is, it looks wriggly no matter how far you zoom in.  In other words, counter to your intuition, the added details do not become less significant.  This means as the $1$-dimensional equipotential curves more closely approach it they increase in $1$-dimensional length without bound, $\to\infty$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox

---

On the other hand, your intuition does hold for the $2$-dimensional area: the area enclosed by each curve in the picture does reduce, so you can bound the area of the Mandelbrot set (which is not known exactly) by the sequence of areas of the curves.  It doesn't converge at all quickly, though.

In fact, as the Hausdorff dimension of the boundary of the Mandelbrot set is $2$, it could have a $2$-dimensional area (but this is not known either)

These are still open research questions that dozens (or hundreds?) of professional mathematicians haven't been able to solve yet, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37229/area-of-the-boundary-of-the-mandelbrot-set for some references.

---

Some other fractals are easier to work with than the Mandelbrot set.  For example, the Koch snowflake curve can be formed by adding smaller triangles to the edges of the existing triangles, forever.  It's not too hard to get explicit formulas for the perimeter and area of the $n$th-level construction, and taking limits as $n \to \infty$ see that the area is finite and get its exact value, but that the perimeter goes to infinity.  The details of the calculations can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake.